# Tabbed Content: Show latest tab on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, tabs

i have a basic tabbed content showing forms in each. example of my site below.
[image]

user submits form, and when page reloads it shows the default first tab. has anyone found a solution for this? the goal if i am on third tab for example, and i hit submit form in that tab, when page reloads it loads the third tab instead of first one?

i am sure i could write some hacky javascript such as:

```
if form submit
check what tab ID form was submitted
force tab open on page load
```

but i have a feeling in 2017 we have came up with a better solution for this type of instance. i appreciate your time and energy reviewing my questions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to prevent the form submission from reloading the page? Regardless, though, show your [mcve] code in your question.

Comment: In 2017 you shouldn't be reloading the page for a form submit. ;)

Comment: ha very true. i can always add a layer of ajax after we get through first beta test!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 2017, you have many possible solutions.
One of them should be match to your situation:

1. Submit the form via AJAX. (No reload, no tab to open)
2. Maybe you have any change like a message after submitting the form, so you know, that you have to open the "form-tab"?
3. Save the current tab in a hidden input field and read this input field on load to see what tab you have to open
4. Save current tab to url and read URL on load to see what tab you have to open

Forget 3 and 4 and work on solution 1 or 2, please.

Comment: Would be the best, I think! 
Have fun! :-)